# Copy certain file to all dependent projects on the CI server

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a post build event in my Data layer project which copies a different config file to the target folder depending on the chosen build configuration, i.e.

```
:: hibernate.cfg.xml is copied by default (set as "Content" file)
:: so override with the appropriate config for the build server

if $(ConfigurationName) == UnitTesting (
  copy "$(ProjectDir)hibernate.cfg.xml.unittesting" "$(TargetDir)hibernate.cfg.xml" /y
)
```

And this gets copied to the appropriate target folder for this project (e.g. `Company.Project.Data\bin\x86\UnitTesting`). However, when I build test projects on our CI server (Bamboo), in all test projects referencing the data layer, I still get the **original file**.

How do I force Visual Studio or MSBuild to copy the appropriate config file to all targets referencing this project for a specific configuration?

**(Update)**

While looking the target folders on our CI server, I noticed that no matter what I do, the target folder on the server always gets the original config file. It turned out that I added these dependencies myself into the `LocalTestRun.testconfig` file which MSTest uses to copy necessary files in place. I did this ages ago and forgot; the reason was also that test projects which referenced the data layer didn't get the config file copied at all.

So finally, the solution was simply to specify a different `.testconfig` file (containing different dependencies) in CI server settings.

Comment: How do you check whether it is an original file? By time, content or other? How do you know other projects reference the original file?

Comment: @starain: that's one of the issues, Visual Studio knows this because they reference the project which copies the file as the part of its build process (file type set to `Content`, `Copy always`). So far I didn't have to check because by dev machine and my testing server had the same configuration. But it turned out that I did something myself a while ago, and forgot about it (see my update above).

Comment: You can post your solution as answer and mark it as answer after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard way:

```
 copy "$(ProjectDir)hibernate.cfg.xml.unittesting" "$(TargetDir)hibernate.cfg.xml" /y

 copy "$(ProjectDir)hibernate.cfg.xml.unittesting" "$(TargetDir)..\OtherProjectOne\bin\$(Configuration)\hibernate.cfg.xml" /y

 copy "$(ProjectDir)hibernate.cfg.xml.unittesting" "$(TargetDir)..\OtherProjectTwo\bin\$(Configuration)\hibernate.cfg.xml" /y
```

Basically, relative paths from $(TargetDir)

Comment: You mean just specify all projects manually? I guess this would work, but at the end it turned out my unit testing config was copying the original file again over the modified one (see my update).

Answer (score 0):

Since my issue was specifically with copying a proper config file for unit testing purposes, I though I might add this as an answer too.

The issue was that I had the following elements in my `LocalTestRun.testconfig` file:

```
<Deployment>
  <DeploymentItem filename="Project\DataLayer\hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</Deployment>
```

which always copied the config file into the target build folder for all test projects. So the solution was to create a different `.testconfig` file and use it on our build server.